# How to make a field NULL using MySQL GUI Tools?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, mysql-gui-tools

I'm using the MySQL Query Browser (part of the [MySQL GUI Tools](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/gui-tools/)) and need to change a field to NULL, but I can't figure out how to do it - if I delete the value it tries to update it to `''`. Typing "NULL" makes it try to update to `'NULL'` (a string).

I know I could just write a query to do it, but that defeats the entire purpose of the tool, no?

Answer (score 143, accepted):

In MySQL Query Browser, right click on the cell and select 'Clear field content' while the focus is in another cell.

In MySQL Workbench, right click on the cell and select 'Set Field to NULL'.

Comment: In MySQL Workbench this setting is now called `Set Field(s) to NULL`, and is the first option in the list.

Comment: Expanding upon @MerlynMorgan-Graham's comment, this option is only visible if you right-click the cell when it does *not* have the text insertion point in it.

Comment: William's detail is crucial. Shift+Del and others mentioned in other answers don't work for me for some reason. However, if all else fails, you can click apply and just edit the update statement (script) field to just say `null`.

Answer (score 10):

In MySQL Workbench, with the cell selected, press `Shift + Delete`

Tested on 6.3.4.0

Answer (score 2):

Right-click on that column and select the

## 'Set field to Null'

option from the context menu.

Answer (score 1):

Removing the contents:

This works for some tools (sorry to hear it doesn't for yours).
This may not appear as null but will when you perform a query.

Comment: in MySQL at least, an empty string is different to NULL. Selecting and deleting the column contents sets it to be an empty string (which doesn't work at all if your column is numerical)

Answer (score 0):

```
Shift + Delete
```

work well in MySql Workbench 8

Answer (score -3):

I'd try Ctrl-0 (zero), because that works in some tools.