# How to convert "null" to "NULL" in MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, null, mysql-workbench

Does anyone know a script to convert a string `null` into `NULL` default value for `MySQL Workbench`?

Comment: This may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/289362/how-to-make-a-field-null-using-mysql-gui-tools

Comment: Title Fix, Formatting Fix

Comment: I want to set all "null" string into NULL without right click on every "null" value... I need an SQL script

Answer (score 0):

query mentioned below should work

```
ALTER TABLE `TABLE_NAME` CHANGE `FILED_NAME` `FILED_NAME` VARCHAR(10) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci NULL DEFAULT ''
```

please let me know if this works.

thanks
amit

Comment: I need to select all "null" inside my table, then convert it to NULL, your script should update the field parameter

Comment: @Fabio in that case my 2nd answer would work, as it seems you want to replace the values inside the tables, and not wanted to actually modify the field of table.

Answer (score 0):

suppose your table is as follows
table name =`table1`

column names and datatypes are as follows

```
   id(int)

   name(varchar(20))
```

To make `name` column values to `null` you can use following query

```
update table1 set name=null;
```

if you want to change all "null" to NULL use following

```
update table1 set name=null where name='null';
```

That query will modify "null" string to NULL in `name` column

Comment: I need to select all "null" inside my table, then convert it to NULL

Comment: @Fabio - answer changed, check now.

Answer (score 0):

In that case, answer mentioned below should work.

```
UPDATE
    TABLE_NAME
SET
    column01 = CASE column01 WHEN '' THEN NULL ELSE column01 END,
    column02 = CASE column02 WHEN '' THEN NULL ELSE column02 END,
    column03 = CASE column03 WHEN '' THEN NULL ELSE column03 END,
    ...
```

*Here only one thing is that you need to write all the column name with which you want to update.*

Thanks
Amit