# MySQL Workbench - How do I set a value to NULL using the GUI?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I want to set a record's value to NULL by just typing into the grid of the currently displayed table in MySQL Workbench and then pressing 'Apply', but when I try to do this, MySQL Workbench sets the value of the record to the string 'NULL'.  Does anybody know how to do what I am trying to do?

Obviously I could accomplish my objective by just typing the MySQL query, but this has happened to me a few times now while testing code and I figure there's an ever slightly easier way to do what I want.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/289362/how-to-make-a-field-null-using-mysql-gui-tools

Comment: Thanks, I searched but didn't find this.