# I am trying to import a CSV file into MySQL workbench. There are some empty cells in a column in a non-empty row that I also want to import

Tags: sql, csv, null, mysql-workbench, data-cleaning

The CSV file that I am importing has 566 rows. E.g., one of the columns called 'Safety Score' has 53 empty cells. I do not want to delete the rows entirely because there are some other useful columns that do have data. I want MySQL workbench to import all the rows including the ones with no data but I am unable to do so. Please help. Thanks!

I tried to replace the empty cells with ",," and "NULL" but MySQL still did not pick those rows up. The default type of the column is 'int'.

Answer (score 0):

Some things to try: -

1. Make the column nullable if it is not
2. Set a default value for the column
3. Have empty cells contain an integer

Comment: How do I make the column nullable? When I import the table using the 'import table wizard' in MySQL workbench, I do not get the option to do so. I can only select the column type.
As for replacing empty cells with integers, I thought about replacing with 0's but that changes the average which I don't want.

Comment: Perhaps this will help ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/289362/how-to-make-a-field-null-using-mysql-gui-tools